# Using a Button control in a ButtonBase derived template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, controltemplate

We have a specific look and feel to buttons in our application and these are defined in a named style for `ButtonBase` which also happens to be the default style for `Button`, `ToggleButton` and `RepeatButton`.

We also have `ToolbarButtons` which are derived from `ButtonBase` and include extra properties such as `Text` and `Icon`. These are used to place a specific text and an icon on a `ToolbarButton`.

The theme for `ToolbarButtons` is defined as follows in `Themes/generic.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:ToolbarButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:ToolbarButton}">
                <Button Command="{TemplateBinding Property=Command}">
                     .. controls to place text and icon etc ..
                </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As you can see I'm using a `Button` control within a control based on `ButtonBase` and binding the `Command` to the `Command` on the contained `Button`. This hack makes sure that I can override the style of the 'Button' used in the `Toolbar` by defining the `Button` default style.

It all seems to work quite well, but it does not feel right using a `Button` inside a `Button`. I'm still wondering if I'm doing the right thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, I don't think that having a button inside another is right. I don't really understand the purpose of it. You want to have the specific button style of your application and be able to override some properties just for your ToolbarButton?

Comment: The reason is that I can now template the inside of a ToolbarButton using the ToolbarButton style while templating the chrome of the button with the default button style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good but you don't have to use a second button in your template, but a [ContentPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use it every time your redefine the template of a [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (a button for example). The BasedOn attribute is useful to override the specific button style.

It looks like this :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:ToolbarButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ButtonBase}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ToolbarButton}">

                <StackPanel>

                    <!-- Image -->
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Image}"/>

                    <!-- Content -->
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You will find the same mechanism with the templates of the [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ([ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), etc) with the [ItemsPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.itemspresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

To take your comment in account, maybe you should override a ContentControl to apply your specific chrome to it:

> public class ButtonContentControl : ContentControl { }

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonContentControl}">

                <!-- Specific chrome -->

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can use it inside the templates of your ButtonBase and your ToolbarButton :

<

```
Style TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:ToolbarButton}">
                <ButtonContentControl>
                     <!-- ContentPresenter or something else -->
                </ButtonContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:ToolbarButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:ToolbarButton}">
                <ButtonContentControl>
                     .. controls to place text and icon etc ..
                </ButtonContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, by overriding the Template you override the template of the ButtonBaseStyle. Also, ContentPresenter does not render the chrome, it only presents what is in the ToolbarButton.Content property. (which we don't use).

Comment: OK, indeed it's quite complex. Don't you think that you should override a ContentControl (ButtonContentControl for example), use your specific style in its template and then use this ContentControl in the template of your ButtonBase AND in the template of your ToolbarButton?

Comment: I don't see any benefit, `Button` itself already is a `ContentControl` and now you're wrapping a button into a button. What might be more applicable is to create a ButtonChrome custom component, but I'm unsure how to propagate `VisualStateManager` states then.

Comment: I'm not wrapping a button inside a button, I'm wrapping a simple ContentControl inside the two button templates. It's a way to centralize your chrome inside one template. But it will not work if you use the VisualStateManager. If you create a ButtonChrome, I think you'll have the same problem as before. Sorry it didn't help you...

Comment: This is the same solution that is used in WPF for some of the default controls: Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ButtonChrome